# Need some assistance with SQL Queries

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm currently working on two different query problems with OracleSQL and I'm in need of some help.

Q1.
Here both queries work perfectly separately. However, I need to put them together into one table/chart instead of having two separate tables/charts. What am I missing/what do I need to do to merge the two? Main difference is the "WHERE Email_List="

---Show counts of customers and average total spending, broken down by customers
who are/are not on our email list.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Customer_Number) Cust_No_w_Email
      ,AVG(Total_Spending) Avg_Spend_w_Email  
FROM CUST_FILE
WHERE Email_List=1;

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Customer_Number) Cust_No_wo_Email
      ,AVG(Total_Spending) Avg_Spend_wo_Email
FROM CUST_FILE
WHERE Email_List=0;
```

Q2.
Similar to the one above, the template below was the closest I can get...

---Show the sum of food spending (hint: SUM function), broken down by job and by
whether or not the customer is on our email list. Display only those groups with sum of food spending greater than 5000. Order the groups by sum of food spending, from highest to lowest.

```
SELECT Job, Email_List AS W_Email, SUM(Food) AS Food_Exp
FROM CUST_FILE
WHERE Email_List=1
GROUP BY Job, Email_List, Food
HAVING SUM(Food)>5000
ORDER BY Job, Food DESC;

SELECT Job, Email_List AS WO_Email, SUM(Food) AS Food_Exp
FROM CUST_FILE
WHERE Email_List=0
GROUP BY Job, Email_List, Food
HAVING SUM(Food)>5000
ORDER BY Food DESC;
```

You are saving a soul if you can help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I've removed the tags for products that are (apparently) not used. Please only tag products involved in your question.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be really helpful.  You appear to have multiple questions here which makes the question too broad.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the first question you can use below query -

```
SELECT 'customers on list', COUNT(DISTINCT Customer_Number) Cust_No_w_Email
      ,AVG(Total_Spending) Avg_Spend_w_Email  
FROM CUST_FILE
WHERE Email_List = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'customers not on list', COUNT(DISTINCT Customer_Number) Cust_No_w_Email
      ,AVG(Total_Spending) Avg_Spend_w_Email  
FROM CUST_FILE
WHERE Email_List = 0
```

For the second question you may try below query -

```
SELECT 'Customer in list', Job, Email_List AS W_Email, SUM(Food) AS Food_Exp
FROM CUST_FILE
WHERE Email_List=1
GROUP BY Job, Email_List
HAVING SUM(Food)>5000
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Customer not in list', Job, Email_List, SUM(Food)
FROM CUST_FILE
WHERE Email_List=0
GROUP BY Job, Email_List
HAVING SUM(Food)>5000
ORDER BY Food_Exp DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first query, you can use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Email_List,
       COUNT(DISTINCT Customer_Number) as Cust_No_w_Email,
       AVG(Total_Spending) as Avg_Spend_w_Email  
FROM CUST_FILE
WHERE Email_List IN (0, 1);
```

One question is sufficient for a question.

Answer (score 0):

For Q1, you could combine the queries in two ways:

1. If you can output the results in multiple columns on a single row, you can use conditional aggregation.
2. If you need to keep the results on separate rows, you can include the email_list column in the group by

Either solution will be more efficient than having separate queries, because you're now querying the table once instead of twice.

This looks like, for the first option:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN email_list = 1 THEN customer_number END) cust_no_w_email,
       AVG(CASE WHEN email_list = 1 THEN total_spending END) avg_spend_w_email,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN email_list = 0 THEN customer_number END) cust_no_wo_email,
       AVG(CASE WHEN email_list = 0 THEN total_spending END) avg_spend_wo_email
FROM   cust_file;
```

and for the second option:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN email_list = 1 THEN 'Y'
            WHEN email_list = 0 THEN 'N'
       END email_present,
     COUNT(DISTINCT customer_number) cust_no_count,
       AVG(total_spending) avg_spend
FROM   cust_file
GROUP BY CASE WHEN email_list = 1 THEN 'Y'
              WHEN email_list = 0 THEN 'N'
         END
ORDER BY CASE WHEN email_list = 1 THEN 'Y'
              WHEN email_list = 0 THEN 'N'
         END;
```

For Q2, you can do it in a single query, like so:

```
SELECT job,
     CASE WHEN email_list = 1 THEN 'Y'
            WHEN email_list = 0 THEN 'N'
       END email_present,
     SUM(food) AS food_exp
FROM   cust_file
GROUP  BY job,
        CASE WHEN email_list = 1 THEN 'Y'
               WHEN email_list = 0 THEN 'N'
          END
HAVING SUM(food) > 5000
ORDER  BY CASE WHEN email_list = 1 THEN 'Y'
               WHEN email_list = 0 THEN 'N'
          END,
          SUM(food) DESC;
```